# 127.0.0.1 works, localhost not, on apache2 server

Tags: windows, apache2, localhost

Installed apache2 on my Win XP SP3, and it's going well if I acess 127.0.0.1, but when I try to type 'localhost' it returns the error that connection to server has been reset. 
I tried to ping 'localhost', it shows something like

```
Reply form ::1: time<1ms
```

In system32\drivers\etc\hosts it is stated that localhost is 127.0.0.1 (*127.0.0.1 localhost*). Why could this happen? I've run out of variants.

Answer (score 3):

::1: is the ipv6 equivalent of localhost - apache seems to only listen on ipv4